# I have 'orders' table and 'items' table. What should be the structure of 'orders_Items' table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables.
One lists all the items I have - the items table.
The other has a list of orders - the orders table.

I want to build another table that can list orderID and the itemIDs. Can anyone help me with the structure of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order_items table
-----------------
order_id
item_id
```

Put a combined unique index on both these columns. And add a foreign key relation to both tables

```
create table orders (id int primary key);
create table items(id int primary key);

create table order_items(order_id int, item_id int);

ALTER TABLE order_items 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_order_id FOREIGN KEY (order_id) references orders(id);

ALTER TABLE order_items 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_item_id FOREIGN KEY (item_id) references items(id);

ALTER TABLE order_items 
   ADD primary key (order_id, item_id);
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d4826/1)

Comment: I don't know how to use a combine unique.. MySQL. Any help?

Comment: Any reason why you've specified it as *unique*, but not *primary*?